# Search and Match Partial Folder Name in Access VBA

Tags: vba, windows, ms-access

I've looked at the top results when typing in the Title of this question, and I hit a dead end...

I have a list of customers, and each customer gets a Job Number [Job_Ref__]. In conjunction with this, each customer gets a folder in SharePoint for all of their documents. The naming convention is Job Number - Last Name, First Name. I want to be able to click a button on my Access form that opens the customer's specific folder, but it keeps opening "My Documents" on my local disk instead.

I've tried the below code without the customer's folder details, and it opens the root of the SharePoint 'drive' with no issue...

Below is what works when I click my OPEN FOLDER button on the form:

```
Private Sub Command232_Click()
Dim folderName As String
Dim folderfullPath As String

folderName = Me.FilePath
folderfullPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\SharePoint Site\Customers 2020\"
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & folderfullPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

When I use folderName is when I hit the issue; I've tried to wildcard the folder name, but to no avail:

```
Private Sub Command232_Click()
Dim folderName As String
Dim folderfullPath As String

folderName = Me.FilePath
folderfullPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\SharePoint Site\Customers 2020\"
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & folderfullPath & folderName & "*", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, as I've hit a pretty big brick wall.
*Of note:* I tried to define folderName = Job_Ref__, but I figured that was too vague, so I added a FilePath field with macros in the Access Form that builds the customer's folder name Job_Ref__ - Last Name, First Name
None of this has worked - am I doing too much with this? XD

Comment: Issue may be with comma and space `, ` in folder name. When I replace with underscore, code works.

Comment: So now we run into the issue: Last Name, First Name is the field `CallerName`, which is the customer's name in the "L, F" format. `Me.FilePath` is just Access putting together `Job_Ref__` and `CallerName`. How can I remedy this? I really don't want to see my customers as Joe,_Don. Am I understanding your answer wrong? I feel like a total idiot at this point. ‍♂️

Comment: Name parts should be in separate fields like FName, MName, LName. Then use concatenation to build any combination desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows allows comma in file name but Shell() function does not like. Options:

1. don't use comma in file name and use Replace() function in VBA to eliminate comma from field value to match file name
2. use FollowHyperlink to open folder - it does accept comma
   `FollowHyperlink(folderfullPath & folderName)`

Comment: `FollowHyperlink` was the best option and worked flawlessly. Much appreciated.